# LLDB Python API type casting

Tags: python, lldb

In GDB Macros, I can do something like this:

```
set $node = (node_t *) $arg0
```

When the node_t is actually defined in a library file. How do I go about doing casting operations of the same nature in LLDB Python macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The easiest is to use SBFrame.EvaluateExpression like:

```
options = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
val = frame.EvaluateExpression("(node_t *) $arg1", options)
```

where frame is the stack frame you in the context of which you are evaluating the expression.

You can also do this without expressions, which is more efficient if you are going to do this a lot.

For instance, if you have an address and a type, then you can use `SBTarget.CreateValueFromAddress` to directly produce the cast value.  You can find types by using `SBTarget.FindFirstType`.

If the value you are interested in is in a register, you can get its value from  `SBFrame.FindRegister`, then cast it with `SBValue.Cast`.  That Cast function doesn't always work when casting one complex type to another - you need the expression parser for that - but for simple C pointers it does work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to clarify one thing, since all the variables in LLDB Macros are of the type lldb.SBValue and the operations like llidb.SBValue().GetChildMemberWithName() just return None if the object is not present, would it be possible to get away with ignoring all the cast operations when doing a 1:1 translation of the GDB Macro to the equivalent LLDB Macro?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Note that gdb's "set" command is a bit confusing, since it either sets a gdb internal variable OR if the thing you are setting is not a gdb variable, it passes the expression to gdb's expression parser and makes gdb "convenience variable" for use in expressions.  In the latter case, it is exactly equivalent to passing the same expression to "print".  In lldb, we don't make the lldb "settings" variables available to the expression parser, so the first usage doesn't really make sense.  But other than that the syntax for convenience variables is pretty much the same.

Comment: Like for example, if I have a GDB command which has a statement: $node = (node_t *) $a, if $node->data do something.  For an equivalent LLDB translation, would I say node = a, if node.GetChildMemberWithName(''). My question is, both node and a are of type lldb.SBValue() as far as the lldb API is concerned. Is there even any neccesity for casting?

Comment: In your first example you started with a register value ($arg0) - which probably has type "unsigned long".  So if you made an SBValue out of that register directly, it would have the wrong type, and GetChildMemberWithName("data") would return an error.  The SBValues are objects that have both a value (e.g. point to some memory in the debugee) and a type (see SBValue.GetType()).  All the GetChildMember... calls work off the SBValue's type.

Comment: OTOH, if the value you are starting from: "$a" in your comment above, was an already correctly typed variable, (e.g. if it was a local variable of type "node_t *" which you created using SBFrame.FindVariable), then casting is unnecessary.

Comment: Just a small question. If I have a variable arg0 that is a hexadecimal address as an argument to my Python method, say def foo(arg0), and I want to create a variable var from arg0 and cast it to a type node_t, how can I use the frame.EvaluateExpression() here?  Basically I want to execute the same statement as it is in the question, but all the variables are Python variables in the lldb macro. It's not possible to use frame.EvaluateExpression() in this instance is it?

Comment: In the above case, I'd have to get the type of node_t (which is a custom structure inside a library file) from somewhere and use SBValue.Cast() to cast the new variable to it right? But assuming my node_t is present in a library function, how do I get the SBType of node_t?

Comment: If you have debug info for node_t, then SBTarget.FindFirstType("node_t") should find it.